# too many values to unpack when working with classes

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

I keep getting the error: "ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 12)". I've checked the dataset, counted all the variables at least 10 times and I'm banging my head against the wall....What am I doing wrong?

Code (Python 3.7):

```
class Corona(object):
    def __init__(self, FIPS, County, State, Country, Updated, Latitude, Longitude,
                 Confirmed, Deaths, Recovered, Active, Combined_Key):
        self.FIPS = FIPS
        self.County = County
        self.State = State
        self.Country = Country
        self.Updated = Updated
        self.Latitude = Latitude
        self.Longitude = Longitude
        self.Confirmed = Confirmed
        self.Deaths = Deaths
        self.Recovered = Recovered
        self.Active = Active
        self.Combined_Key = Combined_Key


    def __str__(self):
        return self.FIPS + "/" + \
               self.County + "/" + \
               self.State + "/" + \
               self.Country + "/" + \
               self.Updated + "/" + \
               self.Latitude + "/" +\
               self.Longitude + "/" + \
               self.Confirmed + "/" + \
               self.Deaths + "/" + \
               self.Recovered + "/" + \
               self.Active + "/" + \
               self.Combined_Key

def loadPeople(filename, slist):
    ifile = open(filename, 'r')
    for line in ifile:
        FIPS, \
        County, \
        State, \
        Country, \
        Updated, \
        Latitude, \
        Longitude, \
        Confirmed, \
        Deaths, \
        Recovered, \
        Active, \
        Combined_Key, \
        = line.split(',')

        s = Corona(FIPS, County, State, Country, Updated, Latitude, Longitude,
                   Confirmed, Deaths, Recovered, Active, Combined_Key)
        slist.append(s)

def main():
    filename = "CoronaVirus.txt"
    sick = []
    loadPeople(filename, sick)

if __name__ == ("__main__"):
    main()
```

First 3 lines of dataset

```
45001,Abbeville,South Carolina,US,2020-04-01 21:58:49,34.22333378,-82.46170658,4,0,0,0,"Abbeville, South Carolina, US"
22001,Acadia,Louisiana,US,2020-04-01 21:58:49,30.295064899999996,-92.41419698,47,1,0,0,"Acadia, Louisiana, US"
51001,Accomack,Virginia,US,2020-04-01 21:58:49,37.76707161,-75.63234615,7,0,0,0,"Accomack, Virginia, US"
```

Comment: Inside the final column you have two commas that are getting split out. You should use the `csv` module to read your file.

Answer (score 2):

You have commas inside some of your quoted fields, so those fields are being split on the commas

```
s = '45001,Abbeville,South Carolina,US,2020-04-01 21:58:49,34.22333378,-82.46170658,4,0,0,0,"Abbeville, South Carolina, US"'
len(s.split(','))
# 14
```

Instead of manually splitting the lines, use the [`csv` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html):

```
import csv

with ifile as open(filename):
    reader = csv.reader(ifile)
    for line in reader:  # line is a list
        slist.append(Corona(*line))
```

Answer (score -1):

Simple problem. but might be hard to eliminate. When you split the line by commas, you also split that last item which has the full location into three parts. Therefore, you get two extra values (`"Abbeville, South Carolina, US"`) becomes three items. Try

```
for line in ifile:
    FIPS, \
    County, \
    State, \
    Country, \
    Updated, \
    Latitude, \
    Longitude, \
    Confirmed, \
    Deaths, \
    Recovered, \
    Active, \
    Combined_Key1, \
    Combined_Key2, \
    Combined_Key3 \
    = line.split(',')
```

And then just:

```
    Combined_Key = ",".join(Combined_Key1, Combined_Key2, Combnied_Key3)
```

Though since it seems the combined key is just the County, State, and Country joined together, you could also try just using those three joined as your combined key. Be warned though, if any of your lines has a differently formatted combined-key, you will need a more sophisticated approach.

Additionally, if you are sure this file is secure, you could just use `csv` to get a list of variables though it takes more time to learn.

Comment: Correct observation, but unfortunately the wrong solution. The correct solution is to use the `csv` module, definitely not `eval` (which I'm not even sure how it's going to work here).

Comment: @DeepSpace csv will work, but I'm giving the simplest and least-setup-needing option. You are right, though, don't know why i used eval instead of csv, fixed.

Comment: @DeepSpace wait shouldn't eval work? It will produce a tuple, sure, but that can just be converted with list()

Comment: @DeepSpace and me giving a simpler and easier-to-understand solution is no reason to downvote.

Comment: Your answer is not "simpler" and "easier to understand" than Patrick's. It's unsafe and wrong. `eval('a,b,c')` does not return a tuple, it causes a `NameError`.

Comment: Fair, forgot eval() doesn;'t like strings. Still, my first solution is completely accurate and solves the problem without signifigantly modifying his code.

Answer (score -1):

Actually from your example `line.split(',')` is not the right thing as your split split in 14 and not in 12. When you split in this way you are also splitting inside the double quotes chars. When you split the following line like this the length will be 14, which is not what you want.

```
45001,Abbeville,South Carolina,US,2020-04-01 21:58:49,34.22333378,-82.46170658,4,0,0,0,"Abbeville, South Carolina, US"
```

You can modify the definition of loadPeople with

```
def loadPeople(filename, slist):
    ifile = open(filename, 'r')
    for line in ifile:
        FIPS, \
        County, \
        State, \
        Country, \
        Updated, \
        Latitude, \
        Longitude, \
        Confirmed, \
        Deaths, \
        Recovered, \
        Active, \
        Combined_Key, \
        = line.split('"')[0].split(',')[:-1]+[line.split('"')[1]]

        s = Corona(FIPS, County, State, Country, Updated, Latitude, Longitude,
                   Confirmed, Deaths, Recovered, Active, Combined_Key)
        slist.append(s)
```

Comment: `line.split('"')[0].split(',')[:-1]+[line.split('"')[1]]` Why? Just use the `csv` module

Comment: Yes he could use the csv module but I wanted to show him a solution and how to split with quotes and double quotes involved, which is sometimes very useful. But yes here you are right the csv module is the right thing.